# How to type python class factory with linter?

Tags: python, factory, mypy, linter

I have this code

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Type


class AbstractFoo(ABC):
    """Abstract foo."""
    foo_attr: int


def foo_factory(foo_attr_val: int) -> Type[AbstractFoo]:

    class Foo(AbstractFoo):
        foo_attr = foo_attr_val

    return Foo


FooA = foo_factory(5)


class FooB(FooA):
    """Public concrete foo."""

print(FooB.foo_attr)
```

This executes just fine, but then I run mypy with `mypy foo.py`, I get an error that looks like

```
foo.py:21: error: Variable "foo.FooA" is not valid as a type
foo.py:21: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
foo.py:21: error: Invalid base class "FooA"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I don't understand what is wrong here and why this type is invalid. What's the way to fix this?

I'm currently on Python 3.9 with mypy version 0.971.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `mypy` does not support dynamic base classes (doesn't matter if they are well-defined). See [this `mypy` issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2477) for more workarounds and details.

If you're happy enough to have a factory producing class without major modifications, you can just pretend that return type **is** that class ([try me online!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ffc740c2c0ac964260fcc96b96e9e993)):

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Type


class AbstractFoo(ABC):
    """Abstract foo."""
    foo_attr: int


def foo_factory(foo_attr_val: int) -> Type[AbstractFoo]:

    class Foo(AbstractFoo):
        foo_attr = foo_attr_val

    return Foo


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    FooA = AbstractFoo
else:
    FooA = foo_factory(5)


class FooB(FooA):
    """Public concrete foo."""

print(FooB.foo_attr)
```

`TYPE_CHECKING` is a special constant that is `False` at runtime and `True` for type checkers. Here you make type checker think that your `FooA` is just a type alias (and on py3.10+ or with `typing_extensions` you can even make it explicit with `TypeAlias` type annotation).

Answer (score -2):

Based on the comments, it appears as if this is a mypy issue.  I did find that with Python 3.10 on MAC, the code still required some changes to run correctly:

```
class AbstractFoo:
    foo_attr: int

def foo_factory(foo_attr: int) -> type[AbstractFoo]:

    class Foo(AbstractFoo):
        AbstractFoo.foo_attr=foo_attr

    return Foo


FooA = foo_factory(5)

class FooB(FooA):
  pass
```

I made two changes:

1. Type -> type
2. foo_attr --> AbstractFoo.foo_attr

Comment: hmm I still get same error when I run mypy.

Comment: Apparently mypy is the culprit here - as discussed in SUTerliakov answer.